# Django - Using "flush" but cannot reset question_id

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to clear all data in my app. I used

```
python manage.py flush
```

It cleared all the questions I created but when I recreate other new questions, the question_id are still saved.

For example, the current question is "What is this?" with question_id=1. After using "flush" and creating new question "what is that?", this new question is marked as question_id=2 although there's no "What is this" question in the admin site.

How can I reset the question_id as well? It means that, after deleting or flushing data, the question_id must start counting again from 1.

Thank you.

Comment: Just don't, it's completely superficial and unnecessary.

Comment: But is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use [`sqlsequencereset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset-appname-appname) command to do that.**

As per [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlsequencereset),

> Use this command to generate SQL which will fix cases where a sequence
>   is out of sync with its automatically incremented field data.

Run the following command and you will see the list of reset commands you can use.

```
django-admin sqlsequencereset
```

If the `app_name` is specified, it prints the SQL statements for resetting sequences for the given app name(s).

```
python manage.py help sqlsequencereset # get help docs on terminal
```